# ¿Porque no me construye el file_field de mi form? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando crear una asociación polimorfica con Nested attributes en Rails, pero mi enemigo aquí es Devise, que no me esta permitiendo construir mi file_field dentro de mi nested, y como consecuencia no me muestra la opcion de seleccionar mi imagen, dejo mis gist completo para que puedan ver mi codigo principal:

https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/b5a7858daacbac671949d1756f4b3175

Espero puedan ayudarme amigos, saludos!

Comment: Me extraña que devise diga nada aquí, si acaso CanCan. Prueba a poner ```f.fields_for resource.pictures``` en vez de ```f.fields_for :pictures```. Mírate esta sección de la documentación http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-form-helpers

Comment: Hola @TlmaK0 si bien hace que aparezca el file_field, falla ya que lo da como parametro no permitido: 

`"enterprise"=>{"email"=>"hernandezalek@l.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "picture"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa9fd897bd8>, @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"enterprise[picture][image]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2016-10-13 00-39-31.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: picture`

No si verificastes mis parametros permitidos

Comment: Solo para confirmar, aunque parezca obvio, sobretodo al ver el código: ¿has verificado que efectivamente lo anidado dentro de `<%= f.fields_for :pictures do |picture| %>` no se está mostrando? revisando el html generado, o agregando algún texto aparte del file_field y que no lo muestre en el explorador ¿O que efectivamente `resource.pictures` llega con un objeto a la vista, independiente que en el controlador se esté haciendo un `.build`?

Comment: Hola @AlterLagos, no hace mucho logre encontrar el problema, y todo se debia a mi enrutamiento, me dio curiosidad de que por mas que modificara el build no hacia nada, entonces empece a sospechar que talvez el form no estaria leyendo el controller generado y efectivamente dentro de mi enrutamiento habia escrito registrations: { "enterprise/registrations" } y la carpeta que me habia generado era una carpeta en plural "enterprises", lo curioso de todo esto es que Rails jamas me dio algun señal de este problema, una simple "s" me hizo perder 2 dias jaja pero bueno una lección para la siguiente =D